# Accessing bottle server running on virtual machine

Tags: python, bottle

I've deployed a bottle application on Windows 2012 server deployed on AWS. I've configured the bottle server to run on 0.0.0.0 using run(host='0.0.0.0', port=9000).

Now, when I try to access the application from browser in my local machine, I get a "could not connect to ...." error. How do I start the bottle server on the VM?

Thanks.

Comment: Umm, no. I tried connecting using the VM's private IP (the one I get when I ipconfig from the VM, which obviously didn't work) and the public IP (the one through which I RDP to the VM).

Comment: Some suggestions please...